# MVC 3 The 'configProtectionProvider' attribute is not allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to encrypt the database connection string in a MVC 3 web.config file using standard RSA encryption, I get the following error message:

The 'configProtectionProvider' attribute is not allowed.

Any ideas on how to encrypt the database connection string in an MVC 3 web site?

Code Sample

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>
              RSA Key
            </KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>
              WcFEbDX8VyLfAsVK8g6hZV....
            </CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>
          OpWQgQ....
        </CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1771774.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

In the `<configuration>` node, add:
 `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"`

You may also need to have 
    `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />`
in your `<system.webServer>` element, in order to start the server.